# Trying to export Ocean Modifier animation as collada file

Tags: animation, export, collada

I'm relatively new to Blender and thus don't have much experience.

I'm attempting to make an ocean animation in Blender, which I have figured out via keyframing.  However, when I attempt to export it to Collada to use in Max/MSP I merely get a single frame, and upon importing it reverts back to the default shape.  I've been told you need to bake it and I've done so via the bake ocean button but it merely caches them rather than bake the animation itself.  I'm completely new and completely lost here, and would appreciate any help.

I'm not attempting to get too deep into blender , I just want to create simple planes with ocean modifiers that I can export as animations in collada.

Comment: Can't you use FBX ? Collada integrations aren't the best. Or you could export an OBJ with MDD if MSP takes it. Provide us the import options you have in MaxMSP so we can help ;)

Comment: I could not export modifier animation. But I can export move animation with collada. I just does not work with modifier animations. I was using collada because the software I am using needs collada format to import.